# Can Application Load Balancer access target group in different VPC?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

From multiple posts, it seems like you're able to connect your LB in VPC A with your target group in VPC B as long as you have the VPC peering / TGW properly setup, For Examples:

[How can I get an AWS Application load balance to forward to a target group in a different vpc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42520675/how-can-i-get-an-aws-application-load-balance-to-forward-to-a-target-group-in-a)

The post is pretty old though and the UI changed a lot, I try to achieve this by running the cli command as below:

```bash
aws elbv2 create-load-balancer \
  --name some-lb \
  --subnets subnet-0968d3a6b028dd147 subnet-025d9a3d24fec3ae6 \
  --security-groups sg-0a44b27d751ebb39c

# Above two subnets in VPC A

aws elbv2 create-target-group \
  --name some-target-group \
  --protocol HTTP --port 80 \
  --vpc-id vpc-B \
  --ip-address-type ipv4 \
  --target-type ip

aws elbv2 create-listener \
  --load-balancer-arn some-arn \
  --protocol HTTP --port 80 \
  --default-actions Type=forward,TargetGroupArn=some-arn
```

I ran into below error message:

```
An error occurred (InvalidConfigurationRequest) when calling the CreateListener operation: The following target groups are in a different VPC than load balancer
```

I have setup the VPC peering between VPC A and VPC B, also altered the routing table in both VPC, am I missing something or does AWS change how this work?

Comment: The target group needs to be in the same VPC as the load balancer. The IPs you attach to the target group will point to the 2nd VPC. Note that this method does not work with autoscaling and may also be more expensive in terms of bandwidth charges.

Comment: @jordanm thanks! can you help elaborate a bit more why this won't work with auto-scaling and why this might be expensive? I would assume this will be the cheapest option   for case like this?

Comment: Because you can't target an autoscaling group, you have to target individual IPs which you must register manually. I don't know for certain but I suspect this setup will have higher cross-AZ bandwidth than a standard setup, which is something they charge for.

Comment: Yes, you can add targets from peered vpc. You can even add them from a vpc in a different region, as long as the VPCs are peered.

Answer (score 1):

As @jordanm mentioned, the ALB and the Target Group **MUST** be in the same VPC, however the target group and the instances **DON'T** need to be in the same VPC.

So in this scenario, the proper way to handle this is to create the target group in the same VPC as the ALB but having external IP being registered to the target group.