# Apache Rewrite domain url in one AWS account to route traffic to EC2 instance in another AWS account

Tags: apache, amazon-ec2, mod-rewrite

I have an url example.com which is in AWS account A.When example.com/rule is searched the traffic needs to be routed to EC2 instance of account B. Iam trying to do it through Apache rewrite rule from Account A Ec2 instance like below

I tried using Apache rewrite rule as below
RewriteRule "^/example.com/rule/(.*)$" "http://example1.com/new/$1" [L,R=301]

When I try this my domain url itself changing from example.com to example1.com which is not intended.

Can you please assist me in achieving traffic routing from Account A to Account B without changing of domin url changing through Apache rewrites or any other possible approach also.Thanks.

Comment: Check this one, I think it's the same setup you want to achieve.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42520675/how-can-i-get-an-aws-application-load-balance-to-forward-to-a-target-group-in-a